# In C#, how can I process all RabbitMQ messages currently on the queue?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

[The basic RabbitMQ tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html) gives an example of how to retrieve messages continuously from a queue:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                 "To exit press CTRL+C");
        while (true)
        {
            var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is retrieve all messages which have been placed onto the queue and then stop.

Here are two examples that would solve my problem

1. If I start my code at 1pm, I want to process all the messages that have been placed on the queue before 1pm.

OR

2. If I start my code at 13:00:00, and it takes 10 seconds for my code to run, I don't mind if it includes messages placed on the queue between 13:00:00 and 13:00:10, as long as it stops as soon as the queue is empty.

I realize that I can probably put a time stamp in my message and check for that, or I could fiddle with timeout values, but I was wondering if there's any built in way to do this properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your description it sounds like queueing is not the right tool, queues are for buffering messages so that they are not produced more quickly than they can be consumed, queues are not designed to persist messages until you decide to process them.  Whilst RabitMQ does support persistent queues, this is more for fault tolerance.  You should be processing messages immediately from your queue, all the time.  If you want to do something with the messages later, then save and retrieve them from some persistent data store like a database.

Comment: It does sound like a MQ is not the solution for your problem. What you could do is create a boolean variable called processQueue and set it to true. Then, do your processing and update the variable to false. The while loop will then change to: while(processQueue) { //... }

Comment: Thanks Praval.  I will consider an alternative approach to MQ.  How would I know when to set the variable to false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the comments it seems that RabbitMQ is not meant for batch processing, so it hasn't been designed for this purpose.

I've also noticed that, when testing the DequeueNoWait method, or attempting to Dequeue with a zero timeout, they didn't work at all, and simply returned null.

The following solution uses QueueDeclare to get a count of existing messages and doesn't require a time stamp or a hacky timeout:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        var queueDeclareResponse = channel.QueueDeclare(Constants.QueueName, false, false, false, null);

        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume(Constants.QueueName, true, consumer);

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Processing existing messages.");

        for (int i = 0; i < queueDeclareResponse.MessageCount; i++)
        {
            var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished processing {0} messages.", queueDeclareResponse.MessageCount);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `QueueingBasicConsumer` it has no recovery built in to it, Use EventingConsumer

Answer (score 2):

What you can do:

1.) First add a timestamp to the message object

2.) Reject the message if the timestamp is not valid. It is an integrated feature of rabbitmq

[Reference](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/08/03/well-ill-let-you-go-basicreject-in-rabbitmq/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, EvilFonti.  I did say in my question, "I realize that I can probably put a time stamp in my message and check for that, or I could fiddle with timeout values, but I was wondering if there's any built in way to do this properly."  But out of interest, what method does one use to get an element using an index?

Comment: I am very sorry, I thought I used an index to access messages in rabbitmq(maybe this was the case in MSMQ but I don't know anymore...). Thats not possible but you can reject it -> I edited the answer.

Comment: In the event that no messages are sent for a while after the application starts, this solution would mean having to wait for the timeout.  I guess that means that one would need to set a short timeout, but long enough to retrieve an existing message.

Comment: Do you mean because of: _Note that RabbitMQ doesn't take care to stop the same consumer getting the message again_ ? I would stop or pause the dequeuing loop after rejecting until you want again get all messages of the queue. That way you will receive all messages at a specific moment in the queue.

Comment: No, I'm talking about Rabbit's Dequeue or Next methods, which have a timeout while waiting for the next message.  I will only know that I've exceeded the time when retrieving a future dated message, or (in the case that there are no future dated messages) I'll have to wait for a timeout before stopping... as I said in my question, "What I want to do is retrieve all messages which have been placed onto the queue and then stop."  In my case I want to stop, because I want to do further processing afterwards.  If you begin your answer with something like "Rabbit doesn't support this," I'll accept.

Comment: You can use `Dequeue(int millisecondsTimeout, out object result)` or `DequeueNoWait(object defaultValue)`. [APIDOC](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v1.4.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-1.4.0-net-2.0-htmldoc/type-RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.html)

Comment: Ah... didn't see that.  Yip, DequeueNoWait should work.  Awesome :)

Comment: I have now tried DequeueNoWait and unfortunately it doesn't work.  If I call Dequeue with a timeout of 10 milliseconds then it does work, but if I reduce the timeout to 1 millisecond,  it doesn't work.  I might end up using Dequeue with a timeout of a few seconds to be safe.